# Squid proxy in kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, proxy, squid

I have a squid proxy installed in one of the AWS ec2 instance and pod running in kubernetes cluster.

I have added the env variable in deployment.yaml file to export the squid proxy LB as below

```
env:
    - 
       name: http_proxy
       value: "http://XXXX:3128"
    - 
       name: https_proxy
       value: "http://XXXX:3128"
```

I can see the access denied if i do a curl request from kubernetes pod console.

```
curl -k google.com
```

The request is not routing to squid proxy if I try to access from the application running in kubernetes pod

Can anyone suggest where I am doing wrong?

How to route all requests from the application running in pod to squid proxy?

Comment: you used env as ingress domain or LB record?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm trying to access a squid proxy behind nginx ingress controller and nginx doesnt even forward it to squid

Comment: To clarify, you want all web traffic initiated by the cluster (i.e. egress, that is, any requests that originated at the cluster as well as the responses data from the internet) to be routed via the proxy? Does this include traffic from the underlying nodes, as well as from all individual pods?

Answer (score 0):

You can try next:

1) Fix this on [docker.service.d](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy) level by creating 
`/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf` with following content:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://XXXX:3128"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://XXXX:3128"
```

Dont forget do afterwards

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

2)If you use own image, you can [build](https://dev.to/zyfa/setup-the-proxy-for-dockerfile-building--4jc8) it with specifying below in Dockerfile. With this approach only current container will use your squid proxy

```
ENV http_proxy XXXX:3128
ENV https_proxy XXXX:3128
```

3) Another way is to look into `/etc/default/docker` (For ubuntu):

```
cat /etc/default/docker
...
# If you need Docker to use an HTTP proxy, it can also be specified here.
#export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/
```

This way you will set up set up proxy for ALL containers and not for only chosen one

I have also found some github [kubernetes-squid](https://github.com/pires/kubernetes-squid) sulotion. PLease take a lokk, but I feel that this is not you need, but anyway..

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried the 2nd option by specifying ENV in docker file but still the same.
The request is not routing to the proxy.

Comment: have you tried other options? maybe you investigated some more details since that time?